# What does !! do?

Tags: command-line

I can run a command like this:

```
tim@Hairy:~$ echo Hello
Hello
```

Then I can run the command !! and it does it again:

```
tim@Hairy:~$ !!
echo Hello
Hello
```

I can even run it with another argument to the previous command:

```
tim@Hairy:~$ !! World
echo Hello World
Hello World
```

So what is the `!!` actually doing? I have struggled to search for it because a [Google for `!!` is fairly... pointless](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=!!).

Comment: @user68186 unfortunatally, Jessie J has taken over that search... https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=bang%20bang&oq=bang%20bang&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i65j69i59j69i60l2.1021j0j1

Comment: or "double exclamation mark".

Answer (score 10):

It's part of [bash's history interaction](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html).

- A `!!` is substituted with the last command as is.
- A `!foo` is substituted with the last command that started with `foo`.
- A `!^` or a `!$` is substituted with the first or last arguments respectively in the previous command.
- A `!n` is replaced with the *n*th command in history.
- A `!-n` is replaced with the *n*th-last command in history.
- ...

Comment: I was the first :)

Comment: Indeed. Have a +1. :P

Comment: You too. Your answer is the best.

Answer (score 4):

It's a very short answer:

`!!` repeats the last command, nothing else.

More "funny" things can you find [here](https://learncodethehardway.org/unix/bash_cheat_sheet.pdf).

---

> I have struggled to search for it because a Google for !! is fairly...
>   pointless.

And a better search for that is this:

```
https://www.google.de/webhp?q=bash+cheat+sheet
```

Answer (score 2):

From `man bash`:

```
!!   Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym for '!-1'.
```

**Test:**

```
$ echo "foobar"
foobar

$ !!
echo "foobar"
foobar

$ !-1
echo "foobar"
foobar
```

Comment: @A.B.: +1 for you too :)

Comment: What a great deal :)